# how to open modal in another page using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I encountered the problem at very beginning of my work. so here is what I want to achieve and according to what I learnt (still learning) I can't find any way around to this problem.
So I have a index.php

```
<?php
    include("core/head_load.php");
?>
<?php
    include("core/login.php");
?>
```

So this file links the login.php and overall head tags together...
now In login.php I have a button

```
<button class="login_btn" onclick="openLoginModal();">Login</button>
```

now this button, when clicked supposed to change the style of the modal from display none to display block....
Now the modal is in a file located in the sub directory

> core/modals/login_modal.php

```
<div id="loginModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h2>Modal Header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some TExt</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

now my loginModal Js Function :

```
openLoginModal = function(){
    var loginModal = document.getElementById("loginModal");
    $("#loginModal").addClass("show");
    loginModal.style.display = "block";
}
enter code here
```

Comment: you would need to either include your login modal in your page to start with and hide it with js or css, or ajax load the modal into the page

Comment: @Pete which do you think is suitable?

Comment: That's entirely up to you - both ways have have their advantages and disadvantages